# I'm working with FileReader class trying to convert read a Blob, However fileReader state stucks on loading forever. What Am I missing?

Tags: javascript, dart, web-audio-api

The idea is to record audio from the microphone, do some processing and later use that audio.
I can't access the data because the `onloaded` event of the `fileReader` never fires, and its state gets stuck on loading forever. The `reader.result` is obviously null, but I don't know why this could be happening.
I also have some limitations on trying things because I'm not dealing with JavaScript directly except for the worklet, and there are some things I would be able to do in JavaScript that Dart compiler doesn't like.

Relevant code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import '../../interfaces/microphone.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:js_bindings/js_bindings.dart';

class GptRecorder implements IMicrophone {
  //late final audioContext;
  final AudioContext _audioContext = AudioContext();
  final FileReader reader = FileReader();
  late final MediaStream _mediaStream;
  late final MediaStreamAudioSourceNode _source;
  late final AudioWorkletNode _node;
  late final MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode _destNode;
  late final MediaRecorder _mediaRecorder;
  late Function _onData;
  String _state = 'stopped';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    stopRecording();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> init(Function onRawDataHandler) async {
    _onData = onRawDataHandler;
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> isRecording() async {
    return _state == 'recording';
  }

  @override
  void startRecording() async {
    final _constraints = {'audio': true};

    final MediaStreamConstraints _mediaConstraints =
        MediaStreamConstraints(audio: _constraints);
    _mediaStream =
        await window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(_mediaConstraints);

    _setupAudioGraph(_mediaStream);
    _mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder(_destNode.stream);
    _mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', _onDataAvailable);
    _mediaRecorder.addEventListener('start', (event) => print('started'));
    _mediaRecorder.addEventListener(
        'stop', (event) => print('it stopped'));
    _mediaRecorder.addEventListener(
        'error', (event) => print('MediaRecorder error: ' + event.toString()));

    _mediaRecorder.start();
    print('actual sample rate: ' + _audioContext.sampleRate.toString());
    print(_mediaRecorder.state);
  }

  _onDataAvailable(Event event) async {
    print(_mediaRecorder.state);
    if (event is BlobEvent) {
      if (reader.readyState == FileReader.done ||
          reader.readyState == FileReader.empty) {
        Blob b = event.data;

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data);
        //final _ = await reader.onloadend!(event); //.onLoadEnd.first;

        if (reader.readyState == FileReader.done && reader.result != null) {
          _onData(Int16List.view(reader.result));
        }
      } else if (reader.readyState == FileReader.loading) {
        // Wait for the previous read operation to complete
        //await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        print(reader.result);
      }

      //
    }
  }

  void _setupAudioGraph(MediaStream mediaStream) async {
    _source = _audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
    _destNode = _audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
    await _audioContext.audioWorklet
        .addModule('lib/models/web_recorder/hello_processor.js')
        .catchError((error) {
      print('Loading error: ' + error);
    });
    _node = AudioWorkletNode(_audioContext, 'pcm16-processor');
    _source.connect(_node);
    _node.connect(_destNode);
  }

  _reset() {
    _state = 'stopped';
  }

  @override
  void stopRecording() {
    _mediaRecorder.stop();
    _reset();
  }

  @override
  void toggleRecoding() {
    _state == 'recording' ? stopRecording() : startRecording();
  }
}
```

Line `await reader.onloadend!(event);` gets the code stuck forever

Worklet node, just in case:

```
class PCM16Processor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    process(inputs, outputs) {
        let input = inputs[0][0]; //tomo la primera señal (deberia ser la unica) y su primer canal (deberia ser mono)
        let output = outputs[0][0]; //idem

        const bitsPerSample = 16;
        const bytesPerSample = bitsPerSample / 8;
        const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(input.length * bytesPerSample);
        const view = new DataView(buffer);
      
        
        for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < input.length; i++, j += bytesPerSample) {
          const sample = Math.floor(input[i] * 32767);
          view.setInt16(j, sample, true);
        }
      
        output.set(new Int16Array(buffer));
        console.log(output);

        return true;
    }
}

registerProcessor("pcm16-processor", PCM16Processor);
```

I would expect to get to the `_onData` function eventually, and this never happens. I have to stop debugging after around 5 seconds or my computer freezes.

I discarded size related issues because web audio api limits to 128 samples per batch.
as the code suggests, I tried checking that events are firing, which they do except for stop and loadEnd. I also checked that `_mediaRecorder` is recording and that worklet output is reasonable.

Also checked `event.data` type, and it says its audio encoded with Opus.

I couldn't find anything about `FileReader` staying in loading forever

Comment: onloadend is an event handler property, it's not a function that returns a Promise  but a property on which you set a vallback that will be called when event fires. But you don't need a FileReader, Blob has a `arrayBuffer()` method, whoch does return a Promise resolving with an ArrayBuffer.

Comment: @Kaiido you are right, thanks. I hadn't seen that method. I can finally see bytes flowing.